# Read in Integers and display in reverse order

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I need to have the user input 5 integers and then push them into a stack, then pop them out in order to display them in reverse order i.e 1,2,3,4,5 is inputted it should display 5 4 3 2 1.  Currently it is just displaying +1.  What is the problem ?

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
   aName DWORD 5 DUP (?)
   nameSize = 5
.code

main PROC

   mov  edx, OFFSET aName
   mov  ecx, 4          ;buffer size - 1


   ; Push the name on the stack.
   mov ecx,nameSize
   mov esi,0
   L1: 
     Call ReadInt
     push eax ; push on stack
     inc esi
   Loop L1
   ; Pop the name from the stack, in reverse,
   ; and store in the aName array.
   mov ecx,nameSize
   mov esi,0
   L2: pop eax ; get character
     mov aName[esi],edx;
     inc esi
   Loop L2
   ; Display the name.
   mov edx,OFFSET aName
   call WriteInt
   call Crlf
   exit
   main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: You only call WriteInt once (and then incorrectly). RTFM.

Comment: What would be the proper solution? I called WriteInt 4 more times and each had an output of +1

Comment: What int does WriteInt write? (RTFM!) What do you want it to write?

Comment: Would it need to be in a loop and write it as its popped?

Comment: Ok so I have successfully printed it in reverse! However here are +'s between each number. Why is this?

Comment: You'd have to ask Dr. Irvine that one.

Answer (score 0):

First off, do as Frank says and RTFM!!!!  You are passing the parameter to WriteInt in the WRONG register!  WriteInt takes a signed binary integer in `eax` NOT `edx`!!!

From WriteInt source:

```
;
; Writes a 32-bit signed binary integer to the console window
; in ASCII decimal.
; Receives: EAX = the integer
; Returns:  nothing
; Comments: Displays a leading sign, no leading zeros.
```

Why use an array if you have to push and pop?

This is wrong:

```
   L2: pop eax ; get character
     mov aName[esi],edx;
     inc esi
   Loop L2
```

Your array is DWORD sized, so you should be adding 4 to esi.

Let's simplify this:

```
.code

main PROC

    mov     ecx, nameSize
GetInput:
    call    ReadInt         ; get input
    push    eax             ; push to stack
    loop    GetInput        

    call    Crlf
    mov     ecx, nameSize
DisplayIt:
    pop     eax             ; get number from stack (LIFO)
    call    WriteDec        ; display it
    call    Crlf
    loop    DisplayIt

   call     Crlf
   call     WaitMsg

   exit
   main ENDP
END main
```

*** EDIT after comment ***

> However here are +'s between each number. Why is this?

Use `WriteDec` as I did instead.

If you were to look at Mr. Irvines source, or read the manual, you would see that `WriteDec` prints unsigned decimals, where `WriteInt` prints signed and unsigned decimals With a + or - to denote signed or not.